# How can I convince iPhone that phone calls are just not that important?

Tags: iphone, call

No matter what I might be engaged in, if a phone call over the cellular network arrives the world as iPhone know it stops until I answer, decline, or ignore.

Can I tell iPhone to simply give me a push notification? Incoming call… in the background

Comment: Are you willing to jailbreak?

Comment: Yes I am willing to jailbreak.

Answer (score -1):

no, your iphone priorities calls because its premiere function is to be just that, a phone. so no, unfortunately not as of today